# values in primefaces edit dialog not getting updated

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have table Providers.I am displaying the table contents in primefaces datatable and performing create,edit and delete operations on it using Jdbc and Tomcat 7.0.

In the edit dialog there are save and cancel buttons. When I click the cancel button and click on the edit button of another row the values of previous row are getting displayed.

I am getting the following warnings when I click on the cancel button:

com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy saveDynamicActions
WARNING: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'editproviderform:btnCancelProviders' because the UIComponent cannot be found

Providers table structure:

ProviderId,
ProviderFirstName and
ProviderLastName

Providers.java

```
public class Providers implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer providerId;
private String providerFirstName;
private String providerLastName;

public Providers() {
}

public Providers(Integer providerId) {
    this.providerId = providerId;
}

public Providers(Integer providerId, String providerFirstName, String providerLastName) {
    this.providerId = providerId;
    this.providerFirstName = providerFirstName;
    this.providerLastName = providerLastName;
}

public Integer getProviderId()
{
    return providerId;
}

public void setProviderId(Integer providerId)
{
    this.providerId=providerId;
}

public String getProviderFirstName()
{
    return providerFirstName;
}

public void setProviderFirstName(String providerFirstName)
{
    this.providerFirstName=providerFirstName;
}

public String getProviderLastName()
{
    return providerLastName;
}

public void setProviderLastName(String providerLastName)
{
    this.providerLastName=providerLastName;
}
```

}

ProvidersBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "providersBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ProvidersBean implements Serializable {

private Providers selectedProvider;

public Providers getSelectedProvider() {
    return selectedProvider;
}

public void setSelectedProvider(Providers selectedProvider) {
    this.selectedProvider = selectedProvider;
}
private Connection con;
@Resource(name = "jdbc/abc")
private DataSource ds;

public ProvidersBean() {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ClinicalStudy");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateProvider() {
    try {
        con = ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Providers SET 
    ProviderFirstName=?,ProviderLastName=? WHERE ProviderId=?");
        ps.setString(1, selectedProvider.getProviderFirstName());
        ps.setString(2, selectedProvider.getProviderLastName());
        ps.setInt(3, selectedProvider.getProviderId());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        clearSelectedProvider();
        ps.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQLException:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    selectedProvider=new Providers();
}

public void clearSelectedProvider()
{
    selectedProvider = null;
}

public void close(CloseEvent event)
{
    event.getComponent().getChildren().clear();
    clearSelectedProvider();
}
```

}

Edit dialog code

```
<p:dialog id="_EditProvider" header="Edit Provider" widgetVar="EditProvider" modal="true"
                  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" position="center" 
                  appendToBody="true">
            <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{providersBean.close}"
                    update=":editproviderform" global="false"/>
            <h:form id="editproviderform">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{not empty providersBean.selectedProvider}">

                    <h:outputLabel for="EdtProviderFirstName" value="ProviderFirstName*:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="EdtProviderFirstName" value="#{providersBean.selectedProvider.providerFirstName}"
                                 required="true" requiredMessage="FirstName must be entered" maxlength="30"
                                 validatorMessage="FirstName must be an alphanumeric value">
                        <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+"/>
                    </p:inputText>

                    <h:outputLabel for="EdtProviderLastName" value="ProviderLastName*:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="EdtProviderLastName" value="#{providersBean.selectedProvider.providerLastName}"
                                 required="true" requiredMessage="LastName must be entered" maxlength="30"
                                 validatorMessage="LastName must be an alphanumeric value">
                        <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+"/>
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:commandButton id="btnUpdateProvider" value="Save" actionListener="#{providersBean.updateProvider()}" 
                                     update=":providersform:providersdt :providersmessages:messages" oncomplete="handleEditProviders(xhr,status,args)"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="btnCancelProviders" value="Cancel" actionListener="#{providersBean.clearSelectedProvider()}"  
                                     oncomplete="EditProvider.hide()"/>

                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Below is the code for the edit button in datatable:

```
<p:column style="text-align: center;">
                    <p:commandButton id="btneditproviders" value="Edit" update=":editproviderform" oncomplete="EditProvider.show()" title="Edit">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item[0]}" target="#{providersController.selectedProvider}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>                        
                </p:column>
```

Comment: Does it help if process="@this" is used for the cancel button?

Comment: I guess that the last code snippet you posted is the one for the delete button and not for the edit button.. Please post the correct code.

Comment: @zargarf Yes I have tried process=@this and immediate=true but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Can you check source after page renders that what id "btnCancelProviders" gets finally, as you know that other container IDs are also prefixed to it?